# How can I sum several items that it has the same code attribute in Xquery?

Tags: xquery

I have a problem with an exercise in Xquery. The logic:

- Obtain the name of products that have been purchased more than 5 times and their unit price

This is the estructure of xml file:

```
<shop>
    <products>
        <product code="P02">
            <name>Hard disk SSD</name>
            <price>320</price>
        </product>
        <product code="P05">
            <name>Keyboard</name>
            <price>30</price>
        </product>
        <product code="P06">
            <name>NAS</name>
            <price>400</price>
        </product>
    </products>
    <purchases>
        <quantity product="P02" client="U300111">5</quantity>
        <quantity product="P05" client="U300111">3</quantity>
        <quantity product="P05" client="U120711">1</quantity>
        <quantity product="P02" client="U120711">7</quantity>
        <quantity product="P06" client="U030512">1</quantity>
        <quantity product="P06" client="U120712">3</quantity>
        <quantity product="P02" client="U120712">1</quantity>
    </purchases>
</shop>
```

I have done this for now:

```
for $x in doc("LMSGI06")/shop/purchases/quantity, $y in doc ("LMSGI06")/shop/products/product
let $z := sum($x)
where $x/@product = $y/@code and $z > 5
return  
<product>
    {$y/name}
    {$y/price}
    <sales>{$z}</sales>
</producto>
```

And this is the result:

```
<product>
    <name>Hard disk SSD</name>
    <price>320</price>
    <sales>7</sales>
</product>
```

I´m trying to add the quantity of products but I don´t achieve to add the products that it have the same product code, and then, in the where clause, to filtrer by the products that have been purchased more than 5 times. Someone does know how can I do this? Thank you very much.

The result should be:

```
<product>
    <name>Hard disk SSD</name>
    <price>320</price>
    <sales>13</sales>
</product>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `group by` if your XQuery version supports it :

```
for $product in /shop/products/product
let $code := $product/@code
group by $code
let $sum := sum(/shop/purchases/quantity[@product=$code])
where $sum > 5
return 
<product>
    {$product/name}
    {$product/price}
    <sales>{$sum}</sales>
</product>
```

Or use `distinct-values()` to simulate the same logic otherwise :

```
for $code in distinct-values(/shop/products/product/@code)
let $product := /shop/products/product[@code=$code]
let $qty := /shop/purchases/quantity[@product=$code]
let $sum := sum($qty)
where $sum > 5
return  
<product>
    {$product/name}
    {$product/price}
    <sales>{$sum}</sales>
</product>
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/d0f2399b5d5e4cb2715df202dd460b91)</kbd>**

Comment: I suspect that product/@code is unique, it's only quantity/@product that can have duplicates. So the grouping here is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The solution from @har07 can be simplified:

```
for $product in /shop/products/product
let $sum := sum(/shop/purchases/quantity[@product=$product/code])
where $sum > 5
return 
<product>
    {$product/name}
    {$product/price}
    <sales>{$sum}</sales>
</product>
```